# Configure Firebase with NX Workspace

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, nrwl-nx, nx-workspace

I am trying to find a way to setup an **Nx Workspace with Firebase** that can deploy different applications lying in that monorepo. The best case would be to have a file structure in the following form:
[image]

In order to deploy the different applications, I would like pass a config argument to the `firebase deploy` command eg `firebase deploy --config firebase.a.json`. When I do this I am getting an error saying "Could not load config file".

Is there a best practice on how to integrate Firebase to an Nx Workspace?
Can i pass config arguments to the firebase deploy command?

Answer (score 2):

You can use nx + @angular/fire, it will generate separate deploy config in seperate project.json.

[image]

--

to work with angular & firebase, I suggest using The official Angular library for Firebase "@angular/fire".

https://github.com/angular/angularfire

--

I already successfully setup nx + angular + firebase. (ps. with only one app in nx monorepo)

details and pictures can be found here:

https://blog-host-d6b29.web.app/2022/11/27/nx-angular-fire.html

I suggest you also try to setup a new nx + angular workspace, walk through my steps and see how it works.